# "biggest failure" versus "greatest failure"

Tags: word-usage, adjectives, comparatives

Which one is the correct way to say it?

> "War is and always remains one of the **biggest** human failures."

or

> "War is and always remains one of the **greatest** human failures."

Or are both adjectives equally good in this case?

Comment: There is no single "correct way" - it depends what you mean. "biggest" tends to indicate size only; greatest may indicate large amounts of other attributes. Compare "He was the biggest man I knew" with "He was the greatest man I knew." In English, the guidance is "If the word is different, it will have a different meaning, or, at least, a different nuance."

Comment: There's also *largest*, *most tragic*, *worst*...

Comment: There is no "right" or "correct" way. It depends on the meaning the writer wants to convey.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Indeed, I'm thinking "_worst_" would be the most appropriate adjective in this case... Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are correct.

big- size

great- degree

He is the greatest man.-degree

He is the biggest man.- size

(positive) big- (comparative) bigger - (superlative) biggest

(positive) great- (comparative) greater - (superlative) greatest

big city- large (size)

great city- famous/important

Sometimes they are interchangeable.

big surprise= great surprise

big mistake= great mistake